# Javascript Browser Language Redirect - What is wrong?

Tags: javascript, redirect, browser

I really thought this would be a simple task to do. But my JavaScript code makes the browser loop the page indefinitely and I really don't know why. I've tried other solutions from stack overflow, but all of them gave the same result. Here is the code:

**SOLVED! THANKS ALL!!!**

Comment: If the URL is `http://website.com` and there's no language context, what else would you expect it to do?

Comment: Okay...but can I fix this with the <html lang="en"> or <html lang="br">?

Comment: I'm not sure, but does `window.location.href = 'http://website.com';` initiate a page redirect although this is your current URL? Don't you need a check if this is your current URL?

Comment: Maybe, let's make this code bigger. What a headache! :P

Comment: The issue is that when you update `window.location.href`, the URL is loaded even if it is the same as the current URL.

Comment: Looks like it's working...I need to upload to the host to final test:
'if (window.location.href != "http://methark.com")' inside the case statement.

Comment: You need this check for all languages. Otherwise you'll get an infinite loop for `br`.

Comment: Yeap...I'll post the complete code if it works...just a sec...

Comment: I'm stupid or lost?
'var language = window.navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
        var languageFistTwo = language.substr(0,1);
        if (window.location.href != 'http://methark.com')
        {
        switch (languageFistTwo) { 
            case "br":
            window.location.href = 'http://methark.com/br';
            break;
            
            default:
            window.location.href = 'http://methark.com';
            break;
        }
    }'

Comment: You can check the source at methark.com or methark.com/br

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: Your logic doesn't make sense. Let's assume my language is `br` and I visit the page. If `window.location.href != 'methark.com` returns `false` I won't be redirected to the correct language. If it returns `true`, I'm caught in an infinite loop.

Comment: Hey Jabaa! I'm working for 10 hours now and I'm a little retarded. I think I know what you mean.

Comment: Move the check into each case.

Comment: Don't post the answer into your question. Either post an separate answer or delete the question.

Comment: Hey @jabaa , did what you said. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think now it's okay (code at the methark.com/br page):

```
<script>
        var language = window.navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
        var languageFistTwo = language.substr(0,1);
        if(window.location.href == 'http://methark.com/br' && languageFistTwo == 'en'){
        window.location.href = 'http://methark.com';
        }
</script>
```